# How can I set a stage result message in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I noticed that, when you use `error('foobar')` in a stage, then "foobar" will be shown if you hover over the stage result, as shown here:

[image: example image]

Is it possible to display a message similar to this if the stage was successful? It doesn't need to have some kind of "button" (like <kbd>Error signal</kbd>) in front of it, I just want to display text of my choice when the user hovers over the stage box, without having to click the "Logs" button.